# Write a program to print the sum of 1 to n. While calculating sum omits the numbers which are multiples of x. Note :Use the concept of continue

Tags: python, python-3.x

Please help me with this I'm not able to omit number of multiple x

```
For i in range(0,n+1):
    if(i%6==0):
        Continue 
        Sum=sum+i
        print(int(sum))
print(sum)
```

Comment: this is not valid python... did you even try to run your program?where is the `x`?

Comment: ```for``` and ```continue``` should not be capitalized.

Comment: im actually not able to solve the question i am trying to solve it with two inputs here is the question "Write a program to print the sum of 1 to n. While calculating sum omits the numbers
which are multiples of x.
Note :Use the concept of continue.
Input first line: Integer n
Input second line: Integer x

Comment: at least write (and post) a program that runs - even if it does not give the correct result. people will not help here if you do not invest that minimal effort. and please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour),
read up on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keywords such as `for` and `continue` shouldn't  be capitalized:

If you're trying to find the sum of numbers that are not multiples of x then you can try this:

```
total = 0
n = int(input("Enter n: "))
x = int(input("Enter x: "))
for i in range(0,n+1): 
    if(i%x==0): 
        continue  
    total += i
print(total)
```

Comment: `sum` is a built-in in python and should never be used as variable name.

Comment: Thank you for that, I thought sum was being used as a variable, sorry about that. I've edited my answer as a result.

Comment: No problem. However as @hiro protagonist correctly said, it is more helpful if you include valid python code even if it doesn't work. You can use an IDE to help solve most validity issues or by researching the error you receive when trying to run the code.